# What do I do when I have very long views with lots of images in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm an iOS newbie and for an app a view will have around 20 photos with a audio player under each so you can listen to someone speak about the images.

How do I go about with this? Would I just make a very long view controller with all the images and audio? It would be a lot of images in total as there are around 5 views with these images and audio.

Or is there a way to have this content elsewhere and get the app to pull the content into the view?

I hope I make sense. Any tutorials/ideas would be a lot of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` (which are very similar code-wise,  but have a different display style).

This will be a good way to manage UX and memory because the cells are just made  for that kind of things.

You can find good tutorials about this on `raywenderlich` or `appcoda`

[For example this one](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)

After this is implemented you'll wanna have a look at customs cells probably, so you can display/move/interact with them in a more... well, customized way.

That you can also find very easily on `appcoda` &/| `raywenderlich`

[For example, here.](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

Answer (score 0):

How about you use `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`. All your Images/Audio components are similar to each other. So you can use advantage of paging. 
It will cost you much less memory since you'll only be consuming the memory for the images( in this case cells) that are showing.

Read a tutorial about `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.